# Chrome Extension: How to default Site Access to "On specific sites" and pre populate them?

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

I am using an `"<all_urls>"` manifest-v2 match pattern which produces the following view in the extension settings:

[image: Chrome Extension current view]

I would like to change it to select "On specific sites" by default and also include two or more pre-populated sites:

[image]

What changes do I need to make to my `manifest.json` file to achieve this goal?

I have read through the seemingly relevant [Manifest V2](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/) parts and could not find anything.
I also tried adding the domain I needed before and after the `all_urls` tag but it just defaulted to the first picture above:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>",
      "https://github.com/*",
      "https://git.musta.ch/*",
    ],
    "css": ["build/style.css"],
    "js": ["build/contentScript.js"]
  }
],
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to change it to select "On specific sites" by default and
> also include two or more pre-populated sites:

You just have to remove "<all_urls>" from the "matches" section and include how many "specific sites" you desire.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also wanted to allow users to manually add other sites and it seems like this feature is preserved with the all_urls pattern. Otherwise, the choices are not editable, so it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

> I also wanted to allow users to manually add other sites and it seems
> like this feature is preserved with the all_urls pattern. Otherwise,
> the choices are not editable, so it will not work.

You have to add "activeTab" in permissions and bind your content script to the user gesture (browserAction click or context menu item selection).
If you choose this way you'll have to inject content script programmatically with **chrome.tabs.executeScript** if your manifest is V2 or **chrome.scripting.executeScript** if your manifest is V3.

if you've chosen V3 you could also consider programmatic declaration of content scripts through **chrome.scripting.registerContentScript** but this API is buggy.
Google is working on it.
There's a opened bug report about it.